# Табличные алгоритмы в C#

Tags: c#

Как реализовать реверс байт табличным методом?

Comment: Что такое реверс табличным методом?

Comment: Упустим эти слова про табличный метод!!! просто реверс массива  байт!!!!

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда что такое реверс? Это побитовая инверсия или изменение порядка битов с прямого на обратный для каждого байта или еще что-то?

Comment: Всё правильно пример изменение порядка битов с прямого на обратный: вход 0 1 1 реверс 1 1 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто реверс то:

```
byte[] bytesArr = ...
Array.Reverse(bytesArr, 0, bytesArr.Length);
```

или

```
byte[] reversed = bytesArr.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: byte[] reversed = buffer.Reverse().ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < reversed.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)(reversed[i]);
            }

// так можно весь буфер повернуть

Answer (score 3):

Ок. Теперь вопрос ясен. Нужно создать таблицу отображающую все множество исходных сочетаний битов в байтах в реверсированные, а именно:

> `00000000 -> 00000000 или 0x00 -> 0x00
> 00000001 -> 10000000 или 0x01 -> 0x80 
> 00000010 -> 01000000 или 0x02 -> 0x40
> 00000011 -> 11000000 или 0x03 -> 0xC0
> 00000100 -> 00100000 или 0x04 -> 0x20
> 00000101 -> 10100000 или 0x05 -> 0xa0
> ...
> 11111111 -> 11111111 или 0xFF -> 0xFF`

Тогда реверс байта - это просто значение таблицы по индексу, равному исходному байту

```
public byte[] LookupTable =
{
    0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xc0, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x60, 0xe0,
    0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xb0, 0x70, 0xf0,
    0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xc8, 0x28, 0xa8, 0x68, 0xe8,
    0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xd8, 0x38, 0xb8, 0x78, 0xf8,
    0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xa4, 0x64, 0xe4,
    0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xd4, 0x34, 0xb4, 0x74, 0xf4,
    0x0c, 0x8c, 0x4c, 0xcc, 0x2c, 0xac, 0x6c, 0xec,
    0x1c, 0x9c, 0x5c, 0xdc, 0x3c, 0xbc, 0x7c, 0xfc,
    0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xc2, 0x22, 0xa2, 0x62, 0xe2,
    0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xd2, 0x32, 0xb2, 0x72, 0xf2,
    0x0a, 0x8a, 0x4a, 0xca, 0x2a, 0xaa, 0x6a, 0xea,
    0x1a, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0xda, 0x3a, 0xba, 0x7a, 0xfa,
    0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xc6, 0x26, 0xa6, 0x66, 0xe6,
    0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xd6, 0x36, 0xb6, 0x76, 0xf6,
    0x0e, 0x8e, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x2e, 0xae, 0x6e, 0xee,
    0x1e, 0x9e, 0x5e, 0xde, 0x3e, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0xfe,
    0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xc1, 0x21, 0xa1, 0x61, 0xe1,
    0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xd1, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x71, 0xf1,
    0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xc9, 0x29, 0xa9, 0x69, 0xe9,
    0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xd9, 0x39, 0xb9, 0x79, 0xf9,
    0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x25, 0xa5, 0x65, 0xe5,
    0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xd5, 0x35, 0xb5, 0x75, 0xf5,
    0x0d, 0x8d, 0x4d, 0xcd, 0x2d, 0xad, 0x6d, 0xed,
    0x1d, 0x9d, 0x5d, 0xdd, 0x3d, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0xfd,
    0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xc3, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x63, 0xe3,
    0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xd3, 0x33, 0xb3, 0x73, 0xf3,
    0x0b, 0x8b, 0x4b, 0xcb, 0x2b, 0xab, 0x6b, 0xeb,
    0x1b, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xdb, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0xfb,
    0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xc7, 0x27, 0xa7, 0x67, 0xe7,
    0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xd7, 0x37, 0xb7, 0x77, 0xf7,
    0x0f, 0x8f, 0x4f, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xaf, 0x6f, 0xef,
    0x1f, 0x9f, 0x5f, 0xdf, 0x3f, 0xbf, 0x7f, 0xff
};

public byte Reverse(byte b)
{
    return LookupTable[b];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

таблицу строить как то неизящно. предлагаю так

```
        byte n = 13; // байт который надо обратить
byte m = 0, l = 1, r = 128;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if ((n & l) == l)
                m |= r;
            l <<= 1;
            r >>= 1;
        }
// m -  байт  с обратным порядком битов
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, может быть это поможет?

- [Tiff.ReverseBits](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/tiff.reversebits1.aspx)
- [Tiff.GetBitRevTable](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/tiff.getbitrevtable.aspx)

Comment: не очень понятно